# Angular 2 starting issue

Tags: angular, typescript

My app was running well but last friday but today it is giving me these starting errors when I try to launch it

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
pae.html:27 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/app
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/app
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1199:29) []
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:165:47) [ => ]
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:460:38) []
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1199:29) []
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:165:47) [ => ]
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:460:38) []
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app

I am new to this and is learning it I would really appreciate some help .

Comment: seems something missing in index.html as the error indicate 404 which means not found

Comment: does the error is at very beginning when you run command `npm start` or when you navigates on /app path ??

Comment: I made a static index page with links to the actual app, it launches to the static page then crash when I start I naviguate to the app. I know it's not a good practice but I didn't know about routing yet

Comment: Are you using npm? You're getting a bundler error (SystemJS), so you probably need npm to manage dependencies you're using.

Comment: Yes I  am using npm but I have no idea on how to manage dependencies using it. some example could help

Comment: Could you post your existing package.json file? that's what tells us what your app uses as dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem it was a dummy one but the issue was with my system.js script`<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>`

, I don't don't how that happened but instead of importing main.js, I imported the folder wher it was located.

Thanks for assisting me